# Disable specific week day according to the day number(0,1,2,....,6)

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to disable all weekdays in JQuery UI datepicker and keep one day on and not disabled according to the day number that i write in the textbox nb.

Is there a way to do that?

My code is:

```html
<p>day number: <input type="text" id="nb"></p>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Notice about day number :

sunday is day 0, monday is day 1 ,..., wednesday is day 3,.....

FOR EXAMPLE : if i write 3 in the textbox nb, so i want only to turn wednesday on in the datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) method

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {        
        var weekDay = parseInt($('#nb').val(), 10);
        if (weekDay === date.getDay()) {
            return [true, '', ''];
        }
        return [false, '', ''];
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x8jcd48c/

Comment: thanks a lot thats absolutly what i want, that works for me :)